# Using OR in an IF Statement

Tags: apex

I entered a contact in the Name and Attendees field and now I want to be able to make sure that if I deleted a Contact from the name field it gets removed from the Invitees field and vise versa. To fix this, I did an IF statement to check if the value of isParent == false OR isInvitee == false. This works for the isParent == false, but it doesn't seem to catch it if the isInvitee ==false. Can anyone help me on why 'OR' is not working and have any suggestions on how to make this work? Thanks.

```
    if (trigger.isUpdate){

        List<EventRelation> erLst = [SELECT EventId, RelationId, isParent, isInvitee FROM EventRelation where EventId IN :trigger.new ];         

        for(EventRelation sObj: erLst ){

            if (sObj.IsParent == false || sObj.IsInvitee == false ){
               delete sObj;
            }
            else{
                sObj.IsParent  = true;
                sObj.IsInvitee = true;
                UpdatedLst.add(sObj);
                update UpdatedLst;
            }
       }
    }
```

Comment: This code needs to be bulkified. You have DML inside a loop

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably not in the code you posted. Read the [EventRelation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventattendee.htm) documentation carefully to understand the `IsParent` and `IsInvitee` differences.

As cropredy commented you do need to follow the normal bulkification pattern:

```
if (Trigger.isUpdate) {

    EventRelation[] ers = [
        SELECT EventId, RelationId, isParent, isInvitee
        FROM EventRelation
        where EventId IN :trigger.new
    ];         

    EventRelation[] deletes = new EventRelation[] {};
    EventRelation[] updates = new EventRelation[] {};
    for (EventRelation er: ers) {
        if (!er.IsParent || !er.IsInvitee) {
           deletes.add(er);
        } else {
           er.IsParent = true;
           er.IsInvitee = true;
           updates.add(er);
       }
    }

    delete deletes;
    update updates;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Keith C The reason I'm doing this logic is because of the mobile limitation in salesforce. I can't put more that 1 contact in the name field so I am forced to put it in the attendees field. But now, when I go into desktop mode, I want to use the Name field for reporting purposes only and not the Attendees field. That's why I want both the Name and Attendees field to sync. The issue now is deleting contacts. If I delete a contact in the Name field, I can't seem to also delete the one in the Attendees field and vice versa.